# What is anyway method to unzip dir before sending files to s3 using multer-s3 (multer-s3-transform)

Tags: node.js, multer, multer-s3

I have an application that sends zip files to aws S3, but I need to unzip that directory first, and then send all the files and send them to my bucket.
I've been trying for a few hours and I have no success, here is my code:

```
import multer from "multer";
import path from "path";
import crypto from "crypto";
import aws from "aws-sdk";
import multerS3 from "multer-s3-transform";

const MAX_SIZE_TWO_MEGABYTES = 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

const storageTypes = {
    local: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: (request, file, callback) => {
            callback(
                null,
                path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "..", "tmp", "uploads")
            );
        },
        filename: (request, file, callback) => {
            crypto.randomBytes(16, (error, hash) => {
                if (error) callback(error);

                file.key = `${hash.toString("hex")}-${file.originalname}`;

                callback(null, file.key);
            });
        },
    }),
    s3: multerS3({
        s3: new aws.S3(),
        bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
        /**
         * Down here I think the magic should happen
         */


        // transforms: [
        //     {
        //         key: (request, file, callback) => {
        //             console.log("TransformsKey");
        //             callback(null, true);
        //         },
        //         transform: (request, file, callback) => {
        //             console.log("Transform");
        //             callback(null, true);
        //         },
        //     },
        // ],
        contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
        acl: "public-read",
        key: (request, file, callback) => {
            crypto.randomBytes(16, (error, hash) => {
                if (error) callback(error);

                const fileName = `${hash.toString("hex")}-${file.originalname}`;

                callback(null, fileName);
            });
        },
    }),
};
```

And here I export my settings

```
module.exports = {
    dest: path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "..", "tmp", "uploads"),
    storage: storageTypes[process.env.STORAGE_TYPE],
    limits: {
        fileSize: MAX_SIZE_TWO_MEGABYTES,
    },
    fileFilter: (request, file, callback) => {
        const allowedMimes = [
            "image/jpeg",
            "image/pjpeg",
            "image/png",
            "image/gif",
            "application/zip",
            "application/rar",
        ];

        if (allowedMimes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
            callback(null, true);
        } else {
            callback(new erroror("Invalid file type."));
        }
    },
};
```

Ps.: Today i use multer like a Middleware

I'm trying some libs and other examples, but I'm not getting anyway.

I hope help.

Comment: have you tried jszip? I've had a good experience with it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jszip

Comment: How do you unzip before the multer sends the files? I can't do this.